# Hide WPF DocumentViewer toolbar programmatically

Tags: .net, wpf, hide, toolbar, documentviewer

This question has a solution:
[How do you hide a WPF DocumentViewer's menu bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649325/how-do-you-hide-a-wpf-documentviewers-menu-bars)

However, it only allows hiding the toolbar through XAML. I need to get this done programmatically.

This answer: [WPF: How can I remove the searchbox in a DocumentViewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322727/wpf-how-can-i-remove-the-searchbox-in-a-documentviewer)  hides the search bar programmatically.

How do I hide the main toolbar via non-xaml code?

Comment: I think it's the simplest and best workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649325/how-do-you-hide-a-wpf-documentviewers-menu-bars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in a `DocumentViewer` which ensures that the toolbar is even there, that being the case a programmatic manipulation of the control at run-time to remove a toolbar which may or may not exist might not be such a good idea. Of course you can do some null-checking and exception handling but that is not very clean either.

For the default aero template the following code will knock out the toolbar:

```
var contentHost = viewer.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", viewer) as ScrollViewer;
var grid = contentHost.Parent as Grid;
grid.Children.RemoveAt(0);
```

I remove the toolbar indirectly as it is not a `PART`, this is the reason why it may not even exist in some themes.

Ideally you should override the template completely.