# WPF DocumentViewer override Print button

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, documentviewer

I have implemented print preview functionality within my application using a custom DocumentViewer (shown below).  I call `PrintDialog.ShowDialog()` before showing the preview so as to correctly create the document based on paper orientation.

The DocumentViewer print button however calls the `PrintDialog.ShowDialog()` prompting the user to chose printer and options once again (which they already did prior to the preview window opening).

Is there a way to have the DocumentViewer print button simply print without calling `PrintDialog.ShowDialog()`?

Here are my method calls:

**ReportViewModel.cs**

```
    public void PrintButtonClick(DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == false)
            return;

        // Get page size based on print dialog printable area (orientation)
        Size pageSize = new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);

        // create new paginator for datagrid
        DataGridDocumentPaginator paginator = new DataGridDocumentPaginator(dataGrid as DataGrid, "Employer Match Report", pageSize, new Thickness(30, 20, 30, 20));
        ...
    }
```

I am doing it this way so that I can correctly generate the paginator with either Portrait or Landscape size values.  Without this the preview document within the DocumentViewer might not display correctly based on orientation chosen.

**PrintDocumentViewer : DocumentViewer**

```
   protected override void OnPrintCommand()
   {
       PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
       printDialog.PrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
       printDialog.PrintTicket = printDialog.PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;

       printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation;
       // Code assumes this.Document will either by a FixedDocument or a FixedDocumentSequence
       FixedDocument fixedDocument = this.Document as FixedDocument;
       FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = this.Document as FixedDocumentSequence;

       if (fixedDocument != null)
           fixedDocument.PrintTicket = printDialog.PrintTicket;

       if (fixedDocumentSequence != null)
           fixedDocumentSequence.PrintTicket = printDialog.PrintTicket;

       XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printDialog.PrintQueue);

       if (fixedDocument != null)
           writer.WriteAsync(fixedDocument, printDialog.PrintTicket);

       if (fixedDocumentSequence != null)
           writer.WriteAsync(fixedDocumentSequence, printDialog.PrintTicket);

       // Create Preview Window and show preview
       string s = _previewWindowXaml;
       using (var reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(s)))
       {
           Window preview = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(reader) as Window;

           DocumentViewer _docViewer = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(preview, "PrintDocumentViewer") as DocumentViewer;
           _docViewer.Document = (fixedDocument != null) ? fixedDocument as IDocumentPaginatorSource : fixedDocumentSequence as IDocumentPaginatorSource;

           // hide the search bar in the PrintPreview dialog
           ContentControl cc = _docViewer.Template.FindName("PART_FindToolBarHost", _docViewer) as ContentControl;
           cc.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

           preview.ShowDialog();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may fill printer and paper size properties, then dialog is not shown.

```
var pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetter, 816.0, 1056.0);
pd.PrintQueue = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print to PDF");
```

To override `Print` command:

```
<DocumentViewer>
    <DocumentViewer.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Print" Executed="Print_Executed" />
    </DocumentViewer.CommandBindings>
</DocumentViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The print button allone can not easily be overridden but I found a way to do it. Even if it may be considered a dirty hack, what counts in the end is the result.

I just overlayed the print button (which is the first button anyway) with a non-visible button that redirects clicks to my own print function. In this example code the search toolbar is also hidden and Ctrl+P is disabled:

```
<Grid>
    <DocumentViewer x:Name="DocumentViewer">
        <DocumentViewer.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Name" Value="PART_FindToolBarHost">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DocumentViewer.Resources>
        <DocumentViewer.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="P" Modifiers="Control" Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand" />
        </DocumentViewer.InputBindings>
    </DocumentViewer>
    <Button Width="32" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0.01" Click="OnPrint" ></Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have resolved this by now, but you may be able to use this question as a base for modifying the template for the DocumentViewer control:

[How do you hide a WPF DocumentViewer's menu bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649325/how-do-you-hide-a-wpf-documentviewers-menu-bars)

There is a link to an MSDN article that should show you how to modify the template so that the print button does what you want instead of the default Print action.